# Array of ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am using an array of arraylists to store words from a string.  I am storing them in the array of array lists by the length of the word.  I am using a switch statement right now, but I have to have 45 cases the way I am doing it, and I was wondering if anyone knew of an easier and shorter way that I could carry out the same operation.  Here's some code:

```
    String temp;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        temp = sc.next();

        switch(temp.length()){

        case 1:
            wordsByLen[0].add(temp);
        case 2:
            wordsByLen[1].add(temp);
        case 3:
            wordsByLen[2].add(temp);
```

I have cases 1-45 and a default.  I would just like to shorten this up, if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: You want to execute each case? If not write break after each case.

Comment: Why not `List<List<String>>`? You'd have to do a `listlist.get(i).add(temp)`...

Comment: Why not Map<Integer,List<String>>?  No need to predefine.

Comment: @CPerkins: A `MultiMap<Integer, String>` would be easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to use switch case over here. try this out :

```
String temp;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            temp = sc.next();
          if(temp.length > 0) {
            wordsByLen[temp.length()-1].add(temp)

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`wordsByLen[temp.length()].add(temp);` --- this should do I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with the `switch`, just do

```
wordsByLen[temp.length() - 1].add(temp)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String temp;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    temp = sc.next();
    wordsByLen[temp.length()-1].add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use one shorter than the length

```
int len = temp.length();
wordsByLen[len - 1].add(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switch you can simply use the following:

```
wordsByLen[temp.length()-1].add(temp);
```